# Google option missing from online accounts after trying to install kde environment

Tags: google, online-accounts

After trying and failing to install kde plasma environment and subsequently removing that install I do not have the option any longer in my online accounts to add google. How can I re add this option?

Comment: **To close voters:** Please don't close this question! OP answered his own question with a solution viable to other readers in the same situation.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Don't we close it given that it's no longer reproducible then? That is, if they don't accept their own answer which it doesn't look like they will.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it's reproducible if it could happen to others and be fixed in the same way. I upvoted the answer, so question is "answered" according to the system now

Answer (score 6):

I was missing the Google accounts plug-in and ran

```
sudo apt install account-plugin-google
```

to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Install kio-gdrive

```
sudo apt install kio-gdrive
```

just run this command on your konsole

Comment: The user removed the KDE environment so installing the kio-gdive will not bring back the Google account option in a his current Gnome based environment.

Comment: If you could explain how the user may install the KDE Plasma environment that would help tremendously @MS Jahid

Comment: System Settings>Personalization>Online Accounts>Add New Accounts>Select Google